# What tense is used when we talk about future with "I wish" structure?

Tags: tense

> 1) I wish I **get** to go to the first day show of Endgame.

Is the aforementioned sentence correct or do I need to change the verb from "get" to "got" as it done in the subjunctive mood.

> 2) I wish I **got** to go the first day show of Endgame?

How would a native speaker say the same thing using the "I wish" structure?

Comment: I wish cannot be used for the future. I hope is used for the future. **I wish I could go** is just a wish in the present. It is not a future like: I'm going to the show tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

*wish* + *would* is used to express a wish for something to happen, or to stop happening:

> - I wish you **would** put those shelves up soon. (He/she has such expectation.)

*wish* + past is used to express a wish for things to be different.

> - I wish I lived in a big city. (He/she doesn't live in a big city.)

To express a wish about the past, the structure *wish* + the past perfect is used.

> - I wish I hadn't lied to her. (He/she lied to her.)

Comment: Thanks very much. So is the sentence " I wish I get to go to the first day show of Endgame" incorrect?

Comment: Yes. I think subject + *wish* + subject + present simple is incorrect in standard English. I suggest you have a look at the examples of some dictionaries.

Comment: @Shivam, this page explains it clearly: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/wish

Comment: All yours are right and it is correct to say simple present is wrong with I wish. I wish cannot express a future, only I hope.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Simple present tense to describe future with the help of wish / hope etc.

e.g. I hope she forgives me if I give her chocolate.

In your example below is correct.

1) I wish I get to go to the first day show of Endgame.

Comment: No, 1) is most definitely not correct.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/154432/hope-future-tense-will-hope-present-tense